# Error: 'Err_too_many_Redirects' This web page has a redirect loop

Tags: django, django-templates

template:

```
<html>
<head><title>Attendance Admin Page</title></head>
<body>
    <center>
    <h1> List of Subfields <h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{% url 'student:list' %}">Classes</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'student:listsec' %}">Sections</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'student:listteach' %}">Teachers</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'student:listatten' %}">Attendance</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</center>
```

I want to provide links of all my selected web pages at a single place for convenience but unfortunately when I tried it throws above error.

Is there any way by which I can make it possible? Please provide a fix.

Thanks! in advance....

Comment: Please include your view and urls... impossible to debug with just a template. The issue is likely in your view or url since that is what decides to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious: your app is caught in a redirect loop. 
Try opening up a network monitor like Fiddler, or the "Network" tab in Chrome's developer tools and look at the response headers to see where it is trying to redirect you to ... that might help reveal what is going wrong here.